# Write data to local JSON file

Tags: android, json

I have JSON file stored in assets folder. Reading from it is easy, but how can I write to it and if the data saved when exiting the app?

JSON:

```
{
    "Home": [
        {
            "Task": "Lapup1",
            "Time": "14:00",
            "Date": "26/12/2016"
        },
        {
            "Task": "Lapup2",
            "Time": "17:00",
            "Date": "26/12/2016"
        },
        {
            "Task": "Lapup3",
            "Time": "15:00",
            "Date": "26/12/2016"
        }
    ]
}
```

Json Parser (Reading):

```
public class JSONParser {

    ArrayList<Task> taskList;
    String json;

    public JSONParser(Context context) {
        taskList = new ArrayList<Task>();
        json = null;
        try {
            InputStream is = context.getAssets().open("Home.json");
            int size = is.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            is.read(buffer);
            is.close();
            json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void getJsonData(String type) {
        try {
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);
            JSONArray m_jArry = obj.getJSONArray("Home");

            for (int i = 0; i < m_jArry.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jo_inside = m_jArry.getJSONObject(i);
                Log.d("DTAG", jo_inside.getString("Task"));
                Log.d("DTAG", jo_inside.getString("Time"));
                Log.d("DTAG", jo_inside.getString("Date"));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

So how can I add something to my Home string?

Comment: There are a lot of libraries dealing with JSON, check gson from google, it will make dealing with JSON much easier

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. The assets are a read only area. To store changes you must store the file somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

You can't write on a file into Assets folder. **The Assets folder is read-only**.

The procedure you need to do, is to copy the JSON file from Assets to External Files Storage. Only in this way you can write into the JSON file and keep it saved.

**1) Copy files from Assets to External Storage:**

```
private void copyAssets() {
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    String[] files = null;
    try {
        files = assetManager.list("");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("tag", "Failed to get asset file list.", e);
    }
    if (files != null) for (String filename : files) {
        InputStream in = null;
        OutputStream out = null;
        try {
            in = assetManager.open(filename);
            File outFile = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), filename);
            out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
            copyFile(in, out);
        } catch(IOException e) {
            Log.e("tag", "Failed to copy asset file: " + filename, e);
        } finally {
            if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // NOOP
            }
        }
        if (out != null) {
            try {
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // NOOP
            }
        }
    }  
}

private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int read;
    while((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1){
      out.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
}
```

**2) Read the JSON file from External Storage:**

```
File JSONfile = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null).getPath(), "Home.json");
```

**3) Use JsonWriter class to write on the JSON and save the file.** Follow this good link from Android Developer: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonWriter.html

Example to save:

```
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(JSONfile);
writer = new JsonWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8"));
```

Important of this point: **remember to close the stream** at the end of writing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want that your Json object will be dynamic you can (one of the choices)
store it in SharedPrefferences and edit it by demend.